# Populate a table based on various inputs

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have three simple inputs for a quotation we're preparing, and I would like to automatically calculate ***all*** the possible  combinations.

For example:

We need to produce Small, Medium, Large and XL garments in red, blue and white colours.  We have quotations from two suppliers to provide the fabric, but the consumption for the sizes and dying is fixed.  So there are potentially 2 x 4 x 3 = 24 pricing combinations.

1. Supplier A - Small - Red
2. Supplier A - Small - Blue
3. Supplier A - Small - White
4. Supplier A - Medium - Red
   ...All the way down to...
5. Supplier B - XL - White

I'd like to set this up so the users can enter the basic inputs, and the formulas would calculate the different combinations by itself.

Importantly, if a new supplier submits a quotation, I would another 12 lines to populate for the newly arrived combinations.

I've tried a few different approaches setting these up as ranges and creating linked drop-downs with the index/indirect formulas or a layered vlookup setup, but haven't been able to get what I'm trying to achieve.

As I'm preparing this for users with basic excel knowledge, I'd simply like one place for them to enter the basic variables, and another to retrieve all the data.

Comment: Correct - each supplier has a single fabric cost per yard, and the different sizes take different yardages.  The different colours have different dye costs.

Example: Supplier A price $2/yard.  SML size 1.8yards.  Red dye cost $0.40/yard.  Total costs would be $4.32.  
I say the consumption on the sizes and dyes as fixed, as those inputs are unlikely to change, but we are likely to get different quotes and counterquotes from suppliers

Answer (score 1):

I’m guessing (i) you are interested in the total cost per item (colour/size), perhaps because the material and the dyeing would be from the same supplier and (ii) you don’t mind some redundancy for the sake of simplicity. Then a table as the upper part below might serve (to be copied for each new quote) with formulae as shown in lower part of the image:

The ‘theory’ is that for additional quotes only the content of the cells highlighted aqua is to be entered and that differences between quote ‘pairs’ (ie MaterialA/DyeB etc – the suppliers named in `A9` and `A10`) are shown in Row21.

[image: SU584780 example]

A new quote or quote/pair would be entered by copying rows 1 to 10 and pasting into say row 25, and then overwriting the values highlighted aqua as appropriate.

The Differences shown arise from a comparison of $2/yard etc against $1.89 and .50/.40/.80 for the dyeing.